# Collapse Layout inside ContraintLayout based on view focus or scroll

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I am looking into `CoordinatorLayout` and `ConstraintLayout` and I want to know if it's possible to achieve something as in :

[image]

As you can see my layout, has:

- the toolbar which is not affected by this. The toolbar is on the main activity and it's not changed.
- under the toolbar there is a fragment loaded with its layout. The layout contains a `ImageView` at the top, some `EditTexts` and a `RecyclerView`

Behavior:

- When user taps on the red EditText I want the layout to scroll up, so that the focused EditText is at the top of the screen with the `RecyclerView` under it.
- At any time the user can scroll down and the initial layout gets shown.

My question is: what would be the best way to create this animation and behavior?

Comment: I'm also very interested in this question. I saw a similar implementation in the Instacart app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to obtain the desired behavior by using in the layout:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
          <AppBarLayout>
               <CollapsingToolbarLayout  
                   app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">
                   <My layout that will get scrolled to the top and be hidden>
               </CollapsingToolbarLayout>  
               <RedEditText which will scroll up until the CollapsingToolbar is collapsed>
          </AppBarLayout>  

          <RecyclerView/>

</CoordinatorLayout>
```